# How to convert a .cov file to html report using bullshtml.exe?

Tags: html, code-coverage, bullseye

I have a coverage report and now i am trying to generate an html report using bullshtml.exe. The coverage file is at location "c:/temp/bullseye.cov", bullshtml.exe is also at same location "c:/temp/bullshtml.exe" so doing as follows:

```
c:/temp>bullshtml.exe -f "bullseye.cov" "c:/temp"
```

So, when i do as above in the command line i get error as

```
"please provide the html output directory".
```

If i do only

```
c:/temp>bullshtml.exe c:/temp
```

I do get files inside the temp folder but it does not make sense to me as i want to convert bullseye.cov to html using bullshtml.exe. Hence please suggest how to get this done and what am i doing wrong is it the command am using wrong or somethingelse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "-v" before specifying the output directory, as below

bullshtml.exe -f "bullseye.cov" -v "c:/temp"

Comment: no its not working by adding -v too agin says "please provide the html output directory"